# How to fade out flatlist top/bottom edges on dynamic background (chat)

Tags: javascript, react-native

hope you can help me out here. I want to create a fade-out effect for comments getting to the edges of the flatlist in a chat component. Very similar to an instagram live.

WANTED OUTCOME (watch the faded comments in the chat):
[Instagram live chat fade out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YttA5.png)

I've already tried with LinearGradient, but since this is a chat over video stream, this doesn't look as smooth as it should. Ideally in my mind I want to lower the opacity of the comments as they get to the edges of the flatlist, but I'm not finding a clear way to do this. I've also tried with onLayout offset events, but still no luck.

I'd appreciate the help!
Thanks,
Best.

Comment: This questions was mentioned in https://medium.com/@saachitech/react-native-faded-flatlist-over-background-image-9651f38ad31c